# KnockoutJS - checkbox on check and computed function

Tags: knockout.js

I'm quite new in `KnockoutJS` and I have a 'simple' question - everytime I click on `checkbox` or `label` I see `1` in the console. But how exacly `changeCheck` 'knows' when it should be invoked ?

Is just `return self.check();` informs `knockoutJS` to invoke `changeCheck` when `check` is changed ? I don't get it. Can somebody explain it for me, please ?

```
self.check = ko.observable(false);

self.changeCheck = ko.computed(function () {
    console.log(1);
    return self.check();
});

<input type="checkbox" id="myCB" data-bind="checked: check" />
<label for="myCB">lorem</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your own attempt to answer the question. Knockout will analyze your computed observable to figure out what other observables are accessed. All these observables will be marked as dependencies for the computed observable (in other words, the computed observable will subscribe to changes of the observable). Whenever an observable changes, it will notify any subscribers of the changed value. For computed observables this means that recomputation will take place. A lot of what I just typed, and a lot of other useful information is provided in Knockout's documentation on computed observables, found [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).